# I have created a simple website app wrapped via Cordova and Crosswalk and it displays a black screen when reopening

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk

I have created a simple website app wrapped via Cordova and Crosswalk and it displays a black screen when reopening

I used Intel XDK.

When I open the app, it displays great. I can select button links to websites and even use the phone back button to go back to the main page.

However when I close and reopen the app - it displays a black screen with a thin blue line on the left side. I have to close it thru the phone soft key app close button.

I added this below but that does not seem to help either

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Handle the back button
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the pause/resume events to handle this I think. How are you closing the app? It sounds like you may just be pausing the app and it doesn't know what to do on resuming.

The below code adds in event listeners for pause/resume.

```
document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
    document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
    document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );
};

function onPause() {
    // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
};

function onResume() {
    // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
};
```